# JSP list all files from folder using path from database

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp

I was saving directly path to file in database because I was uploading maximum one file.
Now one person can add up to 5 files, so I am creating unique folder for them based on their `name`, `lastname` and `phone number`.

In my search JSP page, I got something like this:

```
<c:if test="${Person.zalacznik != null}">                 
     <td>
         <a href="file:///${Person.zalacznik}"><img src="cv_icon.png" alt="CV" height="42" width="42"></a>              
     </td>
 </c:if>
```

but it was path to file. I need to change it so it will do forEach loop for every file in the folder.

So:

`${Person.zalacznik}`  is the path to unique folder from which I need to display all files like this

```
 <td> file list </td>
```

file list created from:

```
<a href="file:///${Person.zalacznik}/filename"><img src="cv_icon.png" alt="CV" height="42" width="42"></a>  <a href="file:///${Person.zalacznik}/filename2"><img src="cv_icon.png" alt="CV" height="42" width="42"></a>
```

How to do that?

Comment: Where are the file names? What will you loop over if `Person.zalacznik` only contains the name of one folder? Having a JSP browse a folder sounds like a security risk, you need to take a step back and start with your backend: Instead of storing one path to one file, you need to store a collection of paths, and then loop over this collection in the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom EL (expression) language function so you can iterate over it.
You might first experiment with some sample code.

The JSP then would look like:

```
<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://www.myurl/mytaglib.tld" %>
<c:forEach var="i" items="${f:listFiles(Person.zalacznik)}">
     <a href="${i.location}"><img src="${i.icon}" alt="$[i.alt}"
     height="42" width="42"></a>              
</c:forEach>
```

The taglib declaration and function will be done as:

```
package my.el;
public class Functions {
   public static class FileInfo {
        private final String location;
        public FileInfo(String location) { this.location = location; }
        public String getLocation() { return name; }
        public String getIcon() { return "icon.png"; }
        public String getAlt() { return "CV"; }
   }
   public static FileInfo[] listFiles(String directoryName) {
       Path path = Paths.get(directoryName);
       ...
   }
}
```

Create a tag library descriptor mytaglib.tld in a directory /WEB-INF/tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd" 
  version="2.1"> 

  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
  <uri>http://www.myurl/mytaglib.tld</uri>
  <function>
      <name>listFiles</name>
      <function-class>my.el.Functions</function-class>
      <function-signature>
          my.el.Functions.FileInfo[] listFiles(java.lang.String)
      </function-signature>
  </function>  
</taglib>
```

In the web.xml we prepare the EL function's URL to be used *directly*.

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

  <jsp-config>
    <taglib>
      <taglib-uri>http://www.myurl/mytaglib.tld</taglib-uri>
      <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tags/mytaglib.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib> 
  </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```